# How do I check whether a path matches a view name defined in urls.py?

Tags: python, django

How do I check whether a path matches a view name defined in urls.py?

Now, urls.py's are set as below:

project/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("", url(r"^app/", include("app.urls", namespace="app")))
```

app/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("", 
    url(r"^$", "app.views.index", name="index"),
    url(r"^(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/(?P<day>\d+)/$", "app.views.edit", name="edit"),
)
```

Then, to check whether a path matches a view name, I wrote this code:

```
def match(path, viewname):
    return path == reverse(viewname)

print(match("/app/", "app:index"))
print(match("/app/2014/07/10", "app:edit"))
```

It seems working properly as to the view named "index" which doesn't have any parameters,
but as to "edit", the code doesn't work (NoReverseMatch is raised).

How do I do to make it work properly with views which has parameters?

**EDIT:**

Thank you for your comments and answers.

My expectation is:

```
print(match("/app/", "app:index")) # => True
print(match("/app/foo/bar", "app:index")) # => False
print(match("/app/2014/07/10", "app:edit")) # => expect True, but NoReverseMatch is raised
```

I found the following code works fine:

```
def match(path, viewname):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
    return resolve(path).view_name == viewname
```

Comment: What is the point of this code? In other words, what is the problem you want to solve with this?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `reverse` wrong.

Try: `reverse("app:edit", kwargs={'month': 7, 'year': 2014, 'day': 10})`.